# Is there a simple way of using the th:data* and th:each attributes together in Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

My intention is to obtain an object inside one of the rows of the table, so I could forward it to a form using a simple JavaScript function. I am not familiar with jQuery so I thought I’ll take an as-simple-as-possible approach. I was thinking of doing this by using the th:data* attribute in combination with th:each, like this:

```
<tr th:each="employee : ${empDetailsList}" th:data-employee="${employee}">
    <td scope="row" th:text="${employee.id}">ID</td>
    <td scope="row" th:text="${employee.firstName}">firstName goes here</td>
    <td scope="row" th:text="${employee.lastName}">lastName goes here</td>
    <td scope="row" th:text="${employee.email}">email goes here</td>
    <td scope="row" th:text="${employee.username}">user name goes here</td>
    <td th:data-employee="${employee}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" th:onclick="showEditForm(this.getAttribute('data-employee'));">Details</button>
</tr>
```

I also tried this approach, moving the th:data-employee from the  'tr' tag to the 'td' tag but the result is the same:

```
<tr th:each="employee : ${empDetailsList}">
...
    <td th:data-employee="${employee}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" th:onclick="showEditForm(this.getAttribute('data-employee'));">Details</button>
</tr>
```

The JS function:

```
function showEditForm(employee){
        console.log('Employee object here: ');
        console.log(employee.firstName);
        console.log(employee.lastName);     
    }
```

As I mentioned I get the same result in both cases. The browser consoles response is:

```
Employee object here:
TypeError: employee is null
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The reason it's not working is because `th:data-employee="${employee}"` doesn't write out employee as a javascript object.  It writes out the default java `toString()` -- something like `com.whatever.Customer@6d06d69c` (which you should be able to easily verify by viewing the source in your browser).  I don't know of a good way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank you  Metroids!
Your answer helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 <p th:each="testScript:${testScripts}">
            <a  th:href="|/scripts/start/${testScript}|" th:text="'Start '+ ${testScript}"/>
            <a  th:href="|/scripts/stop/${testScript}|" th:text="'Stop' + ${testScript}"/>

            <button id="searchButton" name="searchButton" th:onclick="start(this.getAttribute('data_p1'));" type="button"
                    th:data_p1="|${testScript}|"
                   th:text="|${testScript}|">Start</button>
        </p>
```